# Adding hyperlinks to images within an illustrator file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm creating an image for our website that I would like to take up the entire page with smaller images within in, and I would like to hyperlink these images to other pages. Is there a way to do this in illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of several approaches:

1) If exporting the graphic/art to SVG you can use Illustrator's SVG Interactivity panel (window -> SVG Interactivity) and then click an object in your artwork and add in the appropriate javascript (onclick handler, then something like `window.location('http://url/you/want/to/go/to');` in the input field (don't quote me on that - do some research and figure out what you need it to do!). Then export your art as SVG - it should come with your JS either built into your SVG file or linked to it with separate javascript files.

2) Export as a standard web graphic (PNG/JPEG) and then use a web development tool (like Dreamweaver) to turn the image into an image map.

3) Use the web slice tool to slice up your artwork and then export separate pieces, than "reconstruct" your artwork with HTML and your image slices, adding in the links as desired with your HTML editor.

Generally graphic applications, like Illustrator and Photoshop, don't really do links since that's an HTML/web concept and usually better done through an HTML editor.